# Expected Value of the sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

If i have two random variables X and Y, then $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ . However, do X and Y have to be independent ?

Do you know where i can find a proof of this principle ?

Comment: It is based on the fact that $\int (f+g)d\mu=\int fd\mu+\int gd\mu$. Expectations are integrals on the underlying probability space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't. This is called linearity of expectation and holds for all r.v's $X$ and $Y$ - in fact, it holds for a general sum of $n$ random variables regardless of any correlation.

If you google "linearity of expectation" there are lots of articles that have proofs in them